# How to return all data from first two tables and only matching rows from the rest?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 6 tables I am joining together for a procedure: A, B, C, D, E, and F.
My goal is to get all the data where A, and B have matching records (WHEN B has a foreign key that matches a record in A.) I then want to get supplementary information only when data exists for it in the other tables. However, with my current joins, I am being returned no data when there are null joins for the rest of the tables. My current query looks roughly like this.

```
Select A.Title, B.Status, D.Criteria, F.Criteria
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B 
ON B.PK = A.PK
LEFT JOIN C
ON C.PK = A.PK
INNER JOIN D 
ON D.PK_Criteria = C.PK_Criteria
INNER JOIN E
ON E.PK = D.PK
INNER JOIN F
A.PK_Criteria = D.PK_Criteria
```

I was under the impression that the first two left joins would return me all data from that join and the subsequent inner joins would only join the data if there was matches. However, for example, if there are no matching rows in D or F, the query returns nothing. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It looks like your `JOIN`s are the wrong way round. Based on your description shouldn't only the `JOIN` to `B` be an `INNER JOIN` and the rest `LEFT JOIN`s? `INNER JOIN` *requires* a related row to be found in the joined table, where as a `LEFT JOIN` does not.

Comment: @ThomA I hadn't thought about it that way. That makes sense but after making your suggested changes I'm still having the same issue. I will update the question with more precise information.

Comment: Then that would mean that there are no rows where `B.PK` and `A.PK` have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I would use CTE.

```
with t1 as (Select A.Title, B.Status,A.PK,A.PK_Criteria  FROM A JOIN B ON B.PK = A.PK)
select 
    t1.Title, t1.Status, D.Criteria, F.Criteria 
from 
    t1 LEFT JOIN C ON C.PK = t1.PK
    left JOIN D ON D.PK_Criteria = C.PK_Criteria
    left JOIN E ON E.PK = D.PK
    left JOIN F on t1.PK_Criteria = D.PK_Criteria
```

t1 is the result of the selection where records of B match with records of A.
Then you can use t1 to join it to other tables and get the expected result